# When the state changes, the elements are duplicated

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a web app with React and the realtime database from Firebase. The functionality is simple, I get multiple objects from Firebase and iterate through that objects and render a list of values.

The problem comes when I update the database from the Firebase console. When I do that, the state changes and the list rerenders, but it duplicate the list again and again. I don't know if I'm making something wong or my approach is incorrect, but I would like to render a list with information from the objects and when the database is updated, the list updates(changing data or deleting entrys).

Here is some snippets and screenshots.

I get the objects and save them into a object and get the salt/ids for a later iteration.

```
const rootRef = firebase
  .database()
  .ref()
  .child('orders');

rootRef.on('value', snap => {
  this.setState({ allOrders: snap.val() }); //Save the objects in a state objectTaker
  //Iterate through the object and save the salt/id
  const p = snap.val();
  for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        saltsOrders: [...prevState.saltsOrders, key]
      }));
    }
  }
});
```

Here in where I iterate the array of ids and call the object for the data:

```
renderOrders = () => {
 return (
  <ul className="collection" id="listOrders">
    {this.state.saltsOrders.map(num => {
      return (
        <li
          className="collection-item"
          onClick={() =>
            this.setState({
              objectOrder: this.state.allOrders[num],
              showOrder: true
            })
          }
        >
          {this.state.allOrders[num].signedOrder.salt}
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
 );
};
```

And in the render() I have a simple call to the renderOrders:

```
{this.renderOrders()}
```

And here are some screenshot from before and after I change something in the Firebase real-time database.
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of6XM.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee144.png)

Comment: This is strange, you have `allOrders`, then `saltOrders` which is the same thing but just the keys and done with a loop and keeping all the old items so it's duplicated?

Comment: I got problems trying to iterate a object outside of the .on() function. So I iterate there and get the id/salt of the objects. So in the render function I iterate the array of ids so then I call each object.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate `allOrders`? `Object.keys(allOrders).map(key => <div>Salt key: {key}, value: {allOrders[key]}</div>`? Edit: Seems like allOrders is already an array so it's even easier?

Comment: wow! That worked like a charm. Now it's faster and actually solved the duplicated entrys problem. Thank you so much. Can you post the solution above as a response so I can pick it as the solution?

Comment: Cool I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the object directly with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), for example:

```
Object.keys(allOrders).map(key => <div>Salt key: {key}, value: {allOrders[key]}</div>)
```

That way you won't have to do the key loop and worry about the duplicate issue due to the spread in there.